# Differences between LVM in RHEL 5 and LVM in RHEL 6

Tags: lvm

What are the Differences between LVM (Logical Volume Manager) in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 and LVM (Logical Volume Manager) in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6

Comment: Are you expecting certain differences? LVM is implemented by the kernel, so the distribution shouldn't matter that much. Also I believe LVM is quite stable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An old question, I know, but...

One thing I have noticed is that the output of certain commands has changed, e.g. in RHEL6 the `lv_attr` field in `lvs` output has 9 flags, whereas on RHEL5 it only has 6, despite the difference in LVM package versions only being slight (lvm2-2.02.88-13.el5 vs lvm2-2.02.143-7.el6_8.1.x86_64) in the systems I compared.

Another thing is that when creating a mirror from a simple volume, RHEL5 seems to require `--mirrorlog core` to explicitly state that you want to store the mirror log in memory at the expense of resynchronising the mirror every boot, whereas LVM on RHEL6 seems to implicitly assume that is your intention.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking if we compare the version of LVM in RHEL-5 and RHEL -6, then version of LVM is lvm-2 in RHEL-5 as well as RHEL-6. The only difference is that the logical volume can be extended online in RHEL-6, i.e; without unmounting. But in RHEL-5 we need to unmount in order to extend the logical volume.

Thanks,
Syed.